# Add value from function to checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

I have this function where it creates a button with a certain value. In my html form I have a checkbox. I want the value from the buttons to be added in the checkbox. For some reason I am not able to figure it out..

function:

```
var showDate = new Date();
        var months = ["Januari", "Februari", "March", "April", "May", "June","July", "Augusti", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
        var weeks = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuseday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
        var theForm = '<form class="" method="post">

<input id="day"type="checkbox" name="day" value=""> //the checkbox where I want the value to be in 

<input id="button" type="submit" name="btn" value="Send"></form>';

        function drawTable(forDate) {
          var daysInMonth = new Date(forDate.getFullYear(),forDate.getMonth()+1,0).getDate();
          var cellsToDraw = daysInMonth;
          var newdate = forDate.getFullYear() +"-"+ ("0"+ (forDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
          var calendar = document.getElementById("calendar");
          calendar.innerHTML = "";
          for (var r = 0; r < (daysInMonth / 7); r++) {
            var newRow = document.createElement("tr");
            calendar.appendChild(newRow);
            for (var c = 0; c < 31 && cellsToDraw > 0; c++) {
              var day1 = ("0" + (c + 1)).slice(-2);
              var textarea = document.createElement("button");
              textarea.setAttribute("placeholder", day1 );
              newRow.appendChild(textarea);
              textarea.setAttribute("name", "day");
              textarea.setAttribute("value", newdate + "-" + day1); //the value that I want to add in the checkbox
              textarea.innerHTML = day1;


              var textarea1 = document.createElement("div");
              newRow.appendChild(textarea1);
              textarea1.innerHTML = theForm;
              cellsToDraw--;
            }
        }
}
```

All help is appriciated! :)
(I removed some unnecessary code!)

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function(event){
 document.getElementById('day').value = e.currentTarget.value;
});
```

Add an event listener on the button and then assign the value of the button to the value of the checkbox.

Looks a bit like you a rendering a list of checkboxes and buttons, in that case you'll need to write a loop that adds an event listener to each button and it's corresponding checkbox

Comment: Thanks! But, where am I suppose to write this? in the function above?

Comment: Because I added it in the function above, but it did not work. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: it needs to appear after the html has loaded. I don't know how the rest of  your application looks, but in general the html needs to load first before the event can be bound. you should bind the event after the drawTable method has completed.

Comment: if you post a jsfiddle with your progress so far happy to have a look for you :)

Comment: Hi Jane, there's a bit too much refactor required to give you a working answer specific to the code you've given but I have created a fiddle so you can get an idea on what you need to do https://jsfiddle.net/4d0enroy/21/ consider cleaning up your code a bit when asking for help on stackoverflow this makes it easier for us to answer. Hope this gets you what you need.